# $watch not invoked on input change when input doesn't match the pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-directive, data-annotations

I'm using [ngVal](https://github.com/alisabzevari/ngval) to decorate my inputs with AngularJS directives based on the ASP.NET MVC Data Annotations.

My model has the following annotations:

```
[Display(Name="Test Number")]
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^[\d]{6}$", ErrorMessage = "The value must be six numbers.")]
public string TestNumber { get; set; }
```

ngVal is then used to display the error messages associated with the input field.

From what I can determine (with a debug breakpoint in the $watch function) is that the function that should be called on modification of the value in scope is not being called unless the pattern is matched. Here's how the ngVal directive sets up the scope.$watch:

```
var ngval = angular.module('ngval', []);

ngval.directive('ngval', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, iElm, iAttrs, ngModel) {
            var messages = angular.fromJson(iAttrs.ngval);
            var getErrors = function() {
                var errors = [];
                for (var prop in messages) {
                    if (ngModel.$error[prop])
                        errors.push({ validator: prop, message: messages[prop] });
                }
                return errors;
            };
            scope.$watch(function() {
                return ngModel.$modelValue;
            }, function () {
                ngModel.ngval = {
                    hasError: ngModel.$dirty && ngModel.$invalid,
                    errors: getErrors()
                };
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

The result is that initially I see that the field is required but typing something invalid doesn't change the error to the one specified for the pattern - it still says the field is required. This is because the function given to the $watch isn't being invoked. If I enter 6 numbers, the field is valid and modifying the value after that shows the pattern mismatch message. The only exception to this is if I select the contents of the input box and erase it with one key press (del/backspace).

Is this normal behaviour; that [scope.$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope) isn't invoked if the value doesn't match the pattern?

EDIT: I've added a `ng-change` directive on the input and it behaves the same - it's not invoked if the input doesn't match the pattern. A demonstration of the behaviour can be seen in this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/krmQVk0giwCYGxdY5YNS?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the watch is set up against the model, and the value of the property on the model is not set for input changes that do not match the ngPattern. The property on the model is only changed to the input value when it matches the pattern; otherwise the property is emptied (null, undefined or blank - I'm not sure.

The workaround I have in place is to watch the $error properties of the DOM element, which are updated by AngularJS. I added a formItem property to allow the name of the form and input element to be passed to the HTML Helper method so that it can add it to the markup. The watch is now set up as follows:

```
for (prop in messages) {
    scope.$watch(iAttrs.formitem + ".$error."+ prop,
        function() {
            ngModel.ngval = {
                hasError: ngModel.$dirty && ngModel.$invalid,
                errors: getErrors()
            };
        });
}
```

I hope that helps someone out there with the same issue.